# Table inserted in the div block is getting overlapped horizontally when more elements are added to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding some text with DRAG and DROP option within the table declared in the
div section of the code with proper styling. 
When I am resizing my window the table is also getting resized, it means it is working fine.

But when the number of elements are getting more in the table it is getting expanded in the horizontal direction, even when only 66.67 % of window has been provided to that div element.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class = "container">
    <div class="row" >

                  <div class="col-md-8" >

                     <h1 >Selected Courses</h1>
              <table width = "100%"  order="5" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5>

              <tr>
              <td width="100%"  id="red" ondrop="dropIt(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
              <span draggable="true" id="lt1" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><rc>RC</rc></span> 
              </td>
              </tr>

              </table>  

                   </div>


                  <div class="col-md-4" >
                          <h1 >Select Your Courses</h1>

            <table width = "100%" border="5" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5>
            <tr>

            <td valign="bottom" align="left" id="holder" ondrop="dropIt(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
            <span draggable="true" id="lt" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><cse>CSE114</cse></span>
            <span draggable="true" id="srv" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><ams>AMS151 </ams></span>
            <span draggable="true" id="mf" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><cse class = "tooltip">CSE214<span class = "classic"><sp>An extension of programming </sp>methodology to data storage and manipulation on complex data sets. Topics include: programming and applications of data structures; stacks, queues, lists, binary trees, heaps, priority queues, balanced trees and graphs. Recursive programming is heavily used. Fundamental sorting and searching algorithms are examined along with informal efficiency comparisons.</span></cse></span>
            <span draggable="true" id="ids" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><wrt>WRT101</wrt></span>
            <span draggable="true" id="pc" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><ams>PHY131</ams></span>  
            <span draggable="true" id="ltt" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><ams>PHY133</ams></span>
            <span draggable="true" id="srvv" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><ams>AMS161</ams></span>
            <span draggable="true" id="idss" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><cse>CSE215</cse></span>
            <span draggable="true" id="pcc" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><ams>PHY132</ams></span>  
             <span draggable="true" id="pccc" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><ams>PHY134</ams></span>  
              <span draggable="true" id="ids1" ondragstart="dragIt(this, event)"><wrt>WRT102</wrt></span>

            </td>

            </tr>
            </table>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                   </div>
```

[image]

The element is being added from the right box to the left box. In this situation when the no of elements are getting more in left box then it is also acquiring right box place.

Here is the code which is being used for drag and drop.

```
    <script>
            function dragIt(target, e) {
                e.dataTransfer.setData('SpanImg', target.id);
            }
            function dropIt(target, e) {
                var id = e.dataTransfer.getData('SpanImg');
                target.appendChild(document.getElementById(id)); 
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            function trashIt(target, e) {
                var id = e.dataTransfer.getData('SpanImg');
                removeElement(id);
                e.preventDefault();   
            }
            function removeElement(id)  {
                var d_node = document.getElementById(id);
                d_node.parentNode.removeChild(d_node);
            }
            </script>
```

CSS code

```
    .title {
                            color: rgb(0, 207, 255);
                        }

                        .description { /* description is a class */
                            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                            max-width: 705px;  /*color attribute*/ 
                        }

                        .screenshot { /* description is a class */
                            color: red;
                            max-width: 460px;  /*color attribute*/ 
                        }

                        .app {
                            display: -webkit-flex;
                            display: flex;
                        }

                         text {
                                    font-size: 10px;
                                  }
                        /*
                        * {
                           outline: 1px solid red !important;
                        }

                        */
                        * {
                            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                        } 

                        table, td
                        {
                            border-color: #e6e6e6;
                            border-style: solid;
                        }

                        cse {
                            font-family: inherit;
                            font-size: 2em;
                            color: white;
                            padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                            margin: 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            line-height: 1.5;
                            /*outline: 1px solid DeepSkyBlue;*/
                            background-color: rgba(192,0,0,1);
                            border-radius: 5px;
                        }

                        ams {
                            font-family: inherit;
                            font-size: 2em;
                            color: white;
                            padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                            margin: 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            line-height: 1.5;
                            /*outline: 1px solid DeepSkyBlue;*/
                            background-color: rgba(128,100,162,1);
                            border-radius: 5px;
                        }

                        wrt {
                            font-family: inherit;
                            font-size: 2em;
                            color: white;
                            padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                            margin: 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            line-height: 1.5;
                            /*outline: 1px solid DeepSkyBlue;*/
                            background-color: rgba(155,187,89,1);
                            border-radius: 5px;
                        }

                        rc {
                            font-family: inherit;
                            font-size: 2em;
                            color: white;
                            padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                            margin: 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em 0.37em;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            line-height: 1.5;
                            /*outline: 1px solid DeepSkyBlue;*/
                            background-color: rgba(79,129,189,1);
                            border-radius: 5px;
                        }

                        sp{
                            font-size: 1.6em;
                        }

                        cse:hover {
                            background-color: rgba(192,0,0,0.4);
                            font-size: 2em;

                        }
                        wrt:hover {
                            background-color: rgba(155,187,89,0.4);
                            font-size: 2em;

                        }
                        ams:hover {
                            background-color: rgba(128,100,162,0.4);
                            font-size: 2em;

                        }
                        rc:hover {
                            background-color: rgba(79,129,189,0.4);
                            font-size: 2em;

                        }
                        .tooltip {

                                    outline: none;
                                    cursor: help; 
                                    text-decoration: none;
                                    position: relative;
                        }
                        .tooltip span {
                                    margin-left: -600em;
                                    position: absolute;
                        }
                        .tooltip:hover span {
                                    border-radius: 10px 10px; 
                                    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
                                    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
                                    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
                                    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
                                    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                                    font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
                                    position: absolute; 
                                    left: 1em; 
                                    top: 3em; 
                                    z-index: 99;
                                    margin-left: -90px; 
                                    width: 300px;
                                    font-size: 0.4em;
                                    color: white;
                                    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
                        }
                        .tooltip:hover img {
                                    border: 0; margin: -10px 0 0 -55px;
                                    float: left; position: absolute;
                        }
                        .tooltip:hover em {
                                    font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
                                    font-size: 1em; 
                                    font-weight: bold;
                                    display: block; 
                                    padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
                        }
                        .classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
                        .custom { padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em; }

                        .classic {background: #FFFFAA; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; }
```

Comment: how you are adding more elements?? Create a demo if possible!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I added the preview. Please have a look

Comment: Its very difficult to understand with this preview! So it will be good if you add code of how you are adding it to table!!

Comment: drag and drop code added @GuruprasadRao

Comment: and yea!! `CSS` too because this is a **`CSS`** issue

Comment: There is nothing related to css styling other than bootstrap.css in this section.

Comment: See I've created a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m3f6np0u/)** and I don't see same `UI` as you have shown in your preview image!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Added CSS too I thought you are asking for drag and drop CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line and **ALL IS WELL**..

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m3f6np0u/2/)**

```
td span{
    float:left;
}
```

Basically you need to keep your added `spans` floating to `left`

Comment: Anytime!! Happy Coding.. :)